# Where do I place code that fires after the page is returned to the browser

Tags: asp.net

I want to send an Email message after a page is returned to the browser. Where do I place this send Email code so that it does not delay the page that is returned to the browser?

Comment: Do you want to send it from server side or the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET pages have an [unload event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) that fires after the content is returned to the browser. Should be exactly what you're looking for.